# Referencing an Obfuscated DLL

Tags: c#, dll, dotfuscator

I've obfuscated a .Net DLL using DotfuscatorCLI with Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 Post Build events commands. It seems to be successfully obfuscated as no error appeared after that command.

Here is the Command:

> dotfuscatorcli.exe /q
>   /p=SourceDirectory="$(TargetDir)\",SourceFile=$(TargetFileNa‌​me)
>   "$(ProjectDir)Dotfuscator.xml"

And here is the Obfuscator.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE dotfuscator SYSTEM "http://www.preemptive.com/dotfuscator/dtd/dotfuscator_v1.1.dtd">
<dotfuscator version="1.1">
   <propertylist>
      <property name="SourceDirectory" value="This Path Will Be Replaced By Visual Studio" />
      <property name="SourceFile" value="This Filename Will Be Replaced By Visual Studio" />
   </propertylist>
   <trigger>
      <filelist>
         <file dir="${SourceDirectory}\" name="${SourceFile}" />
      </filelist>
   </trigger>
   <output>
      <file dir="${SourceDirectory}\Dotfuscator\" />
   </output>
</dotfuscator>
```

Now, when I reference that DLL in another project and try to access its public members; I can no longer access them. It is as if they are not defined/public in that DLL, and they are not available in intellisense too.

If I view that DLL in Object Browser, it shows classes with some weird names e.g. h, I, m, n etc.

Am I missing something here, in order to consume that DLL?

Any response, hint or solution will be appreciated.

Comment: Public types and members should not be obfuscated.  Usually an obfuscator knows that...what are you using?

Comment: Also, don't just link to another post and make us go there to figure it out....linking is OK, but provide the substantive details *here* in your question body as well.

Comment: I've updated the question and wrote the command that I'm using. Do let me know if any other information is required.

Comment: Have you done any research on how to use dotfuscator?  I googled it and quickly found this: https://www.preemptive.com/images/stories/Dotfuscator/Excluding_Types.html  and this: https://www.preemptive.com/images/stories/Dotfuscator/Excluding_Methods.html

Comment: I googled it too and followed one article from MSDN, I'll check your links too. here the link I used: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh977082(v=vs.107).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help from @Nathan, I'm able to resolve the problem I had. Here is the content from updated Obfuscator.xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
    <!DOCTYPE dotfuscator SYSTEM "http://www.preemptive.com/dotfuscator/dtd/dotfuscator_v2.3.dtd">
    <dotfuscator version="2.3">
       <propertylist>
          <property name="SourceDirectory" value="This Path Will Be Replaced By Visual Studio" />
          <property name="SourceFile" value="This Filename Will Be Replaced By Visual Studio" />
       </propertylist>
        <input>
        <asmlist>
          <inputassembly>
           <option>library</option>
             <file dir="${SourceDirectory}\" name="${SourceFile}" />
          </inputassembly>
       </asmlist>
      </input>
       <output>
          <file dir="${SourceDirectory}\Dotfuscator\" />
       </output>
    </dotfuscator>
```

I know that If I use dotfuscator UI, it automatically enables library mode but I choose CLI approach on purpose. I want to automate and give generic solution to my 35+ DLLs which are referenced in one project.
So now with this approach, I hope this will not only automate my obfuscation process but also speed things up since it's a post build event command approach. In short, all I need to do is Press Build solution button, and its done.

Hope this would help others. Let me know in case of any ambiguity or concerns, or if you have any other suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you have probably *disabled* [Library Mode](https://www.preemptive.com/dotfuscator/ce/docs/help/5.27/obfuscation_overview.html#library-mode) for that assembly. Try re-enabling it, which will tell Dotfuscator to automatically exclude public types and members from renaming.

Comment: Thanks @Nathan. I've updated my question and there you can see the XML file. I didn't disable any mode explicitly.

Comment: @AzazulHaq, the problem is that at the config-file level, you have to *enable* library mode. If you use the UI to generate the config file, it will enable it by default. The config file in that blog post doesn't have it on, so that's the source of the confusion. If you want to see how to enable it by hand-editing the XML, please see [the relevant section in the user guide for Pro](https://www.preemptive.com/images/stories/Dotfuscator/webframe.html#Library_Mode_By_Assembly.html).